# Why does the EU restrict the maximum power drawn by various consumer electronics instead of taxing them higher?

Tags: european-union, law, energy-policy

According to [this article](https://www.digitaltrends.com/home-theater/eu-efficiency-standards-would-ban-8k-4k-tvs/), EU restrictions related to various appliances will go into effect on 2023.03.01. If nothing changes, most high-end TV cannot be sold in the EU:

> If nothing changes between now and then, there won’t be a single 8K TV
> that can be sold in the EU. The rule also will affect a couple of 4K
> OLED TVs, 65-inch QD-OLED TVs, and at least one high-performance 4K
> QLED TV.

The article provides more details and critiques how the EU computes the figures for such restrictions.

I am wondering about the rationale of such a policy which might create various problems (e.g. producers cannot sell some products, make quality compromises to meet the restrictions, and higher production costs) and not consider alternatives like higher taxation. Examples:

- higher tax for products with power consumption above some thresholds
- higher prices of electricity based on various consumption thresholds

Theoretically, higher taxation instead of restriction means no unhappy customers due to not being able to buy some stuff and higher income for the states. So, it is not clear for me why restriction instead of taxation.

[TimesOfIndia](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/gadgets-news/why-several-high-end-tvs-may-be-banned-in-europe-in-2023/articleshow/95003473.cms) provides more details about the expected maximum power and the actual power required by some 8K TVs:

> (..) the EU wants 75-inch 8K TVs to consume 141 watts...Samsung
> 75-inch 8K TVs reportedly consume at least 303 watts... similar LG
> models consume 219 watts ... TVs from TCL consume 356 watts.

Note: While [Why do governments encourage saving resources instead of simply
raising the price on them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/why-do-governments-encourage-saving-resources-instead-of-simply-raising-the-pric) is similar, there are two main differences:

- I am asking about the EU, not individual governments
- I am mentioning taxation on energy-inefficient products as opposed to resource taxation

Comment: It's not the only place where there is a hard limit. For example speed limits, alcohol selling to underage person's, the amount of liquids you can take with you on an airplane. Maybe taxation there would also be a good idea.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think these are comparable: I guess that the "speed limits" are mostly in place to save lives, alcohol selling to underage persons because alcohol (ethanol) is a toxic product that greatly affects younger brains, and "the amount of liquids you can take with you on an airplane" is a counter-terrorism measure. I would place all these examples under the "health and safety" restrictions. Effectively banning 8K TVs does not seem to fit the category.

Comment: You probably need to look into the health and safety issues around power generation, then. Human-induced climate change at the very least is a reason to incentivise efficiency and cap usage; the sheer level of oil-/NG-based power generation in Europe is also a major problem.

Comment: Note that 2032 was a typo.  The date of concern is 2023.

Comment: @alamar [This article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/gadgets-news/why-several-high-end-tvs-may-be-banned-in-europe-in-2023/articleshow/95003473.cms) provides the figures: "the EU wants 75-inch 8K TVs to consume 141 watts...Samsung 75-inch 8K TVs reportedly consume at least 303 watts... similar LG models consume 219 watts ... TVs from TCL consume 356 watts"

Comment: Well, it makes sense now because 300W is a large amount of power these days, especially provided TVs tend to run continuously. It's twice the limit!

Comment: Reading the [directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02019R2021-20210501&from=EN#tocId17) it seems possible to provide different operating modes with higher consumption. So the television has to be capable of low-power operation, but some features (such as HDR) are allowed to consume more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do governments encourage saving resources instead of simply raising the price on them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/why-do-governments-encourage-saving-resources-instead-of-simply-raising-the-pric)

Comment: @Alexei - Nixon's national "55mph" limit was to save energy. 
(Oil in particular)  on the other hand energy limits are also health and safety in the long term

Comment: @Alexei There are definitely difference but one argument you mentioned was increasing government income by taxing additional activities like wasting energy for example. In this way all hard limits could be replaced by soft ones in order to increase revenue even more. But maybe revenue maximization isn't the goal.

Comment: 300 f*king watts for a TV? The idea is to push the electronics companies to introduce new models with lower consumption. It is not to make people watch less TV. The people writing these laws talk to engineering consultants first, you know. I am sure the electronics companies have the resources necessary to comply.

Comment: It seems a good idea, so we will have washing machine with a heater of 600W instead of 1.2kW, a much larger volume of insulation, lower loading capacity and longer running time to heat up the water to the same temperature.

Comment: Assuming that's true, doesn't it sound more like bureaucracy than anything sensible?

Comment: @EarlGrey Maybe washing mashines shoud measure Wh/batch instead of Ws of power. Suggest it to your representative.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Because the EU's intention is that TVs actually consume less energy, not that people simply pay more for waste, or that states collect more taxes.

If the rich can afford to pay more, it can easily be invested in technological development that improves efficiency.

Also I suspect one low-tech solution the rich could have to large and dim screens, would be to simply fit and use blackout curtains when viewing them, rather than expecting the screens to function in daylight.

This is the reason why cinemas are dimly lit environments when the film is playing, because projector technology has always limited how bright the viewing screen can be.

If the inefficiency of larger and finer screens cannot be overcome by technological means, then the intention is probably also to limit screen sizes and resolutions to a sensible maximum, implied by the power consumption limits.

The assumption that consumers will be less happy due to these restrictions is I'm afraid an unproven suggestion. I enjoyed television and film just as much at PAL resolutions on a 14 inch screen.

Comment: You can't buy a 44" 8k television set because it draws 50W, but if you are rich you are sitll permitted to buy a huge 88" TV that draws 175W or 3.5 times more.

Comment: @alamar, indeed, but the primary purpose is to promote the energy efficiency of technology, not specifically to stifle large screens or set absolute energy limits on everyday tasks (like consuming television programming). I only remarked because the OP made corresponding points.

Comment: "This is the reason why cinemas are dull environments when the film is playing, because projector technology has always limited how bright the viewing screen can be."  Might want to change "dull" to "dimly lit".  While your not wrong, dull also means "lacking excitement" which isn't something I see often in cinema experiences (did have someone fall asleep because she was bored with the film once, so...)

Comment: @hszmv, yes I meant "dimly lit" haha!

Comment: @Steve I edited it since you didn't. You are welcome to undo or improve my change

Comment: @user253751, I was inclined to leave it there for the potential humour, but I won't haggle now it's changed.

Comment: Consumers may be equally happy with their screens - but not with the fact the government is limiting the screen size. I've noticed a tendency for people to be unhappy whenever the government does stuff.

Comment: @user253751, probably because big-screen manufacturers have paid propagandists to agitate not only the particular issue but the very principle of government control, in a way that governments tend less often to fund propagandists to attack private industry and industrialists.

Answer (score 43):

Tax is a matter for national governments not for the European Union.

There are some attempts at harmonisation of fiscal policy across the Eurozone, but details of tax, such as a sin tax on big TVs, is firmly a matter for the national government.

So the reason that the EU isn't taxing TVs is simple  *The EU doesn't tax anything!*.  Tax is simply not an option for the EU.

Comment: The same also applies to setting energy prices, which the question mentions.

Comment: That is the real answer. The EU does not hold any authority whatsoever when it comes to taxation. It is only allowed to do *Ordnungspolitik*, ie. decide on the outer frame within which markets are allowed to act freely. Regulation through fiscal politics, which from an economic standpoint can make more sense in many cases by setting progressive taxes towards prohibitive prices is not in the power of the EU. That being said, domestic governments *that could do this kind of tax* tend to leave market control to the EU as it is not exactly popular anyways.

Comment: This is not true, while EU cannot itself directly raise taxes, EU can force individual countries to implement the tax EU wide. In fact EU is already proposing legislation forcing countries to have minimum corporate taxes, and in exactly the same way EU could implement any taxation scheme it wants. The execution is delegated to state level but EU has the power to force them to implement taxes https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/pl/qanda_21_6967

Comment: @1muflon1: Note that the page linked explicitly mentions "Member States will need to unanimously agree in Council.". That's necessary because the EU cannot follow the normal process. This ban however could be passed by ordinary majority vote.

Comment: @MSalters but they have to unanimously agree because thats how EU institutions work. EU has not just parliament but also The Council of the European Union. This council is however EU institution. It would be equivalent if instead of house of representatives US would just give every state 1 seat, except The CotEU has more power to legislate. Some decisions like this have to be unanimous. By the way EU EC takes ownership of the proposal, so EU itself is arguing this is its proposal

Answer (score 31):

**Because limits are the only 99% certain way to actually cause manufacturers to innovate and use more energy efficient technology.**

Consider for example what has happened with vacuum cleaners. I have a vacuum cleaner bought in 2011, that has nominal power of 2000 watts and maximum power of 2200 watts. Today, that would be illegal in EU.

On the other hand, a typical cordless vacuum cleaner maybe has a 60 watt-hour battery.

Let's calculate how many minutes a cordless vacuum cleaner would run if it was impossible to build a good vacuum cleaner with less than 2000 watt power usage.

60 watt-hours / 2000 watts = 0.03 hours = 1.8 minutes

So, that's it. With a cordless vacuum cleaner, you would be able to use it for 1.8 minutes if it was using 2000 watts of power and had a typically sized 60 watt-hour battery.

What EU recognised is that vacuum cleaners had ridiculously high power usage. They recognised that it's possible to build a reasonable vacuum cleaner, with good enough suction, using 500 watts as opposed to using 2000 watts. So, in other words, what was available in the marketplace in 2011 was terribly inefficient.

The same is true with televisions. A 75-inch (16:9) TV has a surface area of 1.55 square meters. At a reasonable brightness of 250 candelas per square meter, that's 388 candelas. Lambert's cosine law says that this requires 1220 lumens of luminous flux, assuming the worst case displayed picture (all white). If you disagree, turn on a 75-inch television, put the picture to white, and compare how well it lights your room compared to a 1220 lumen LED light bulb.

State of the art LEDs today are about 164 lm/watt (I used Osram P9 as an example). So, to produce 1220 lumens, you need 7.4 watts.

If Samsung's 75-inch TV consumes 303 watts, it's about 41 times less efficient than it could be.

It's true that today's televisions are inefficient, for example the light diffuser at the back wastes some light, and color filter blocks two thirds of the light. But still... 300 watts to produce 1220 lumens. That's ridiculous! In fact, a 60-watt incandescent light bulb produces 800 lumens, so Samsung's TV is more than three times less efficient than an incandescent light bulb, which is so outdated technology that today it's banned for its inefficiency.

Besides, the 7.4 watts is the worst case. If the television uses advanced technology to create light at every pixel as opposed to creating a constant background light and filtering that away at every pixel, I'd say a typical picture would use half that, 3.7 watts.

I fully agree with EU that manufacturers need pressure to reduce the power consumption of televisions.

Comment: Your arguments depends on 250 candelas per square meter being "reasonable". Unfortunately, you don't give an explanation for that. How did you arrive at that statement?

Comment: My computer monitors, HP Z24i G2, have 300 candelas per square meter maximum brightness. I don't use them at maximum brightness.

Comment: The corded/cordless vacuum comparison doesn't appear reasonable, because the products are designed to accomplish different tasks. Better would be to show an older corded vacuum had substantially higher energy use than a current generation one. Even then, your comparison would, likely, be showing *both* technological improvements and changes in capability to get the new generation under the restrictions. A real comparison of such would need to take into account how long the average consumer needed to use each model to accomplish the same task (i.e. total energy consumed for the task).

Comment: Companies started building ohmic resistors into vacuum cleaners for no other reason than to increase the power draw. This was because consumers would assume "More power = More suction" and hence choose their vaccums by the amount of power drawn.

Comment: While it does not invalidate your point, it’s worth pointing out that that 300W is not all going into the illumination. The signal decoding and display driver chips also eat a nontrivial amount of energy, and that's ignoring the small computer that most TVs these days include as well. That’s not going to be enough to fully account for the power discrepancy, but it does mean that realistic consumption targets are much closer to something like a 30W peak consumption if you assume maximal efficiency of the display itself.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn the TV set produces very specific light patterns (and sound, but the sound is less of an issue compared to everything else). The signal processing is exactly the same for the same number of pixels no matter how big the display is. This fact was accounted for when the power limits were drafted.

Comment: @fraxinus My comment above was not intended to dispute the power limits themselves, but to point out that this answer does not account for that, instead discussing things as if those components simply did not exist or did not matter (the signal processing _usually_ does not, the display driver might depending on the display technology, and the computer found in ‘smart’ TVs definitely does).

Comment: @Mookuh, sooo, I get an electric heater to go with my vacuum cleaner, for free? What a win!

Comment: @Mookuh that's pretty crazy - citation needed

Comment: It was a claim made by our electronics professor at university, I'll see if I can find any more information on it. He was generally a serious figure, so I didn't question it. It seemed to be in line with company behaviour after things like e.g. the Phoebus Cartel

Answer (score 9):

To complement other good answers, another potential contributing factor is that:

**A strict ban is likely simpler and cheaper to implement.**

Or at least cheaper in direct costs to government and business. If you want to introduce a new tax, you need to setup the beraucracy to collect the tax and to enforce that it is paid. And this needs to be ongoing: you need to at least sometimes somewhere actually check that the number of sold/imported items matches the number on the tax declaration. It is not unheard of that the cost of collecting a tax becomes larger than the amount of money collected.

On the other hand a complete ban can quite safely be checked very few times (most likely just at certification of the appliance for the EU market, where it becomes just one more item to check among many others), since most manufacturers produce large batches of identical products. It also targets the manufacturers/certificate holders (usually few in number and big) which have more to lose and are generally easier to track than importers/resellers (many smaller companies).

**EDIT:** Commenters have raised the possibility that the cost of a new tax could be made negligible by introducing a new VAT bracket for offending applicances. I agree this could be one of the easiest way to do it, but it definitely is not without cost. I didn't dig deep, but immediately the first result when searching ["cost of multiple vat rates"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&q=cost+of+multiple+vat+rates&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) on Google Scholar is [Agha & Haughton 1996](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2109932) who do empirical evaluation of VAT collection and note that "compliance [to VAT] is substantially lower with multiple VAT rates" and with multiple VAT rates "Compliance
costs rise as the tax forms become more complex and accounting records need to be more complete". I do not have strong opinion/data on what would happen in any specific case, but I hope this is enough to show that a non-trivial cost is at least possible.

This still does not preclude that taxation would benefit the *society* as a whole more, but the direct costs to government/business could IMHO plausibly at least sometime be lower for bans than for taxes. Especially in situations like this where the proposed tax is unlikely to have large total volume. If the tax was a side effect a larger framework of carbon/energy consumption taxes, the calculus could be different.

Comment: On one hand, this is the general problem with bureaucracy: it's much easier and cheaper to ban something than to do more nuanced management, people (or technology) be damned. On the other hand, bureaucracy begets bureaucracy, and it doesn't mind expanding (nor the costs), so I'm not sure this is the full explanation.

Comment: @Zeus agree it's definitely not the full/only explanation, but I think it could have contributed.

Comment: This is factually incorrect. All EU states already have VAT tax. Hence government would have nearly 0 additional burden from imposing additional product-specific tax. Also generally speaking modern taxation is virtually all just fixed cost (which is already paid to collect other taxes). Modern governments don’t send out tax collectors to collect every penny like in Middle Ages. Everything is automated nowadays. I would love to see some serious data showing this would be cheaper to implement than tax. Moreover, research clearly shows that these sort restrictions have higher welfare costs

Comment: For the society. So this is very misinformed opinion.

Comment: @1muflon1 show your research

Comment: its not mine research but research of top experts in the field (including Nobel Prize winners for environmental econ). Here is just small sample of work that claims environmental taxes are the best solution and that they do reduce use: Nrodhaus (2007), Cremer et al. (1998), Mankiw (2007), Frank & Bernanke (2007). Anderson (2003),
Gruber (2007), Holcombe (2006), Hyman (2008), Steineman, et al. (2005), Stiglitz (2000), Ulbrich (2003). Thomas (2000), Kahn (2005), Keohane et al (2007) and Tietenberg (2003). 
Waldman (2004). The case for taxes is as well supported as cause for vaccine use in PH

Comment: @1muflon1 totally agree that in many cases taxation might be more beneficial _to the society_ than bans. My claim is that in some specific cases (including this one) a ban _might_ be cheaper at least in its direct costs _to government and companies_ (for compliance). Added a quick reference in that direction.

Comment: @MartinModrák right but that is multiple VAT rates, lets say one good has 10% and other 15% VAT rate, that leads to issues such as lets say hamster food having 10% VAT and bunny food 5% VAT, and people substituting away from hamster to bunny food creating problems. Rather, what I meant was that state already has huge bureaucratic apparatus that collects VAT adding to it a department of environmental taxation (which is what you have to look at) would have negligible costs because all auditors electronic systems etc are already there. Also environmental taxes create that substitution on purpose

Comment: whole point of environmental taxes is to make people substitute away from consuming too much energy so the vice of multiple VAT rates is virtue of environmental taxation. Moreover, even if the regulation could be shown to be cheaper for the government (I have my doubts but ok perhaps it could be shown if that regulation is kept extremely simple and there isnt strict oversight) it would not be cheaper for government + companies for sure since tax precisely allows for companies for whom its too expensive to switch to keep using it and rather reduce more consumption where its easier to switch

Comment: Just purely on compliance, its is much cheaper for government to use existing tax bureaucracy where auditors have to check whole accounting of the firm anyway (few extra T accounts in era of computers is nothing) whereas to control the products you have to higher engineers, waste few products once in while for control (otherwise company can just create single batch) and have apparatus that enforces fines for all this. In addition you need to anyway get budget and extra taxes for all this.

Answer (score 5):

Because neither governments, nor (con)federations such as EU, behave optimally and taxes are unpopular, and people do not understand that capping energy use creates implicit taxes anyway.

From a scientific perspective tax would be better policy ([Nordhaus 2007](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1093/reep/rem008?journalCode=reep)).

- First rule of rational policy-making is that people respond to incentives. By selecting appropriate level of the tax energy consumption can be driven down to arbitrary low level pre-selected by the social planner.
- Taxes are superior to quantity controls as they allow for consumption to be reduced at points where the damage to welfare will be minimal, whereas quantity reductions do not have any good mechanism to achieve that.

People who claim that pollution taxes are just way to pay for pollution without reducing it are public administration equivalent of anti-vaxxers since evidence for this is at least as strong as public health evidence for use of vaccines.

However, taxes are deeply unpopular with public. Similarly to vaccines where people have fear of autism and other side effects for which there is no credible evidence, when it comes to taxes people fear that new taxes will come at their expense (which is true) whereas quantity controls are somehow free and they will not have to pay for them or if they recognize that there are costs they believe these costs are at least lower than the costs of taxes (which is blatantly false according to best available evidence and scientific consensus).

You can see it playing out in the real world. When Macron tried to impose higher price of gasoline in France, which is environmentally justified and more optimal then lets say capping the use of gasoline, France experienced bloody des gilets jaunes (yellow vests) protests. Democratic countries have to respect wishes of the electorate, regardless of whether the policy is optimal for society or not.

Comment: and now, interestingly enough, France has a naturally very high price of gasoline and shortages, caused by refinery worker strikes. I heard that Macron was considering forcing them to work at metaphorical gunpoint

Comment: "[the public believes] quantity controls are somehow free" don't attribute to stupidity what can be attributed to rational self interest. the lower/working classes know that they have a better shot of securing at least some access to the commodity when it is capped rather than taxed, even more so if it is price controlled at the same time. this isn't an "emotional" reaction, it's a rationally self-interested one - no matter how "irrational" any birds-eye analysis says it is.

Comment: @John I am not claiming irrationality, but lack of information or even misinformation. These quantity controls result in higher prices since we are not talking about rationing of the product but rather controlling some attribute of the product. It can be shown that this would lead to higher price. However, that’s off topic, as clarified above I am not talking about irrational behavior, rational behavior can be stupid, being anti-vaxxer can be fully rational if you believe vaccines are poison. I think it’s so plain that masses are generally misinformed about nuances of optimal public policy

Comment: That we can treat it as an axiom. Similarly the response of masses I describe can be fully rational (even though empirical evidence shows that people are not always fully rational - there is a whole behavioral literature about type I and II cognition), yet rational behavior can easily be stupid. Jumping out of window believing you will fly is rational, cutting out your eye and burning believing you will get blessed by Odin is rational as well provided both are honest beliefs. Rationality just requires people have set of consistent preferences. The preferences themselves can be dumb

Comment: Or based on misinformation (eg people not learning biology and reading hoax articles about link between polio vaccines and autism).

Answer (score 5):

Taxes are supposed to discourage manufacturers indirectly, by making their products more expensive, which drives away customers. This is a very indirect mechanism which is not guaranteed to work.

Instead of innovating on the energy consumption front to avoid the higher taxes, manufacturers could try to get around this problem by reducing production costs by the amount that the taxation adds, so they arrive back at the market price.

For instance, they could lower quality, which would be bad. And others would have to follow suit, as they would be undercut.

Even worse, they could also change the product to make it LESS energy efficient (as they get taxed anyway), which could presumably be done using older, cheaper technology, with fewer patent license fees to be paid for energy-saving innovations.

In short, taxation as a steering mechanism could lower standards, increase energy consumption and stifle investment in innovation to reduce consumption.

Direct restrictions on the other hand are predictable and easy to implement.